# Diffie Hellman in actionscript

Tags: encryption, actionscript, diffie-hellman

I'm not a mathematician and haven't been able to create a procedure myself. Googled for a day and read a lot of posts, but there seems to be no working example around in AS: is anyone willing to share some working source to get me up and running??

Answer (score 0):

The [Hurlant Crypto library](http://crypto.hurlant.com/docs/) has an implementation of BigInteger class. It does not have DH directly, but you can use the BigInteger class to roll your own

```
var g:BigInteger = new BigInteger("5");
var x:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
var rnd:Random = new Random();
rnd.nextBytes(x, (512>>3));
x.position = 0;
var p:BigInteger = new BigInteger(x);
p.primify(512, 1);
x = new ByteArray;
rnd = new Random();
rnd.nextBytes(x, (512>>3));
x.position = 0;
var b:BigInteger = new BigInteger(x);
b.primify(512, 1);
var B:BigInteger = g.modPow(b,p);
```

send `g`,`p`,`B` to the other end and when `A` comes back do the calcs for `s`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Regretfully, this takes up to 17 seconds on a standard system because of the huge keys that are used (up to 4096 bytes) so Hurlant is pretty much unusable (I need a solution within 100ms, not 17,000 ms:-) Thanks anyway 0xc3!